# SQL Script Automation Help Required

Tags: sql-server, command-line, automation, scheduled-tasks

I am wondering how I can launch SQL Express and run a set of scripts for:

- Clients
- Cash Movements
- Orders etc

at a specific time of the day:

- Clients @ 5:01
- Cash Movements @ 5:02
- Orders @ 5:03 etc

These scripts would need to execute and then download the data to a network location of...

```
L:\Projects\Automations in CSV format
```

I cannot sadly use the SQL server Management studio (full version) and so am looking at either some help in creating command line script / batch files?  Which I have been passingly informed may be the way forward or advice on a software package that I can purchase that would open the SQL Express and run and download the files to location or any other alternatives that may be out there.

Comment: You can run your sql scripts from the command line by using "sqlcmd -i yourscript.sql" and use the Windows Task Scheduler to execute them at a specific time. You can output your sql request in CSV format by using the select statement to print out ";" characters

Comment: Thanks for the help so far, however I am still stuck!  I didn't add enough information I feel...

Comment: The server I connect to is a remote one ip address 10.xxx.xxx.xx with a username and password required Is this still possible?

Comment: Of course it is, you can use -S switch to specify the remote server, instance name and port, and use -U and -P to specify username and password. Have a look to the sqlcmd doc : http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms162773.aspx

Comment: if there are any dependencies in the data processed in Clients, Cash, Orders, then it will be safer to have one script run all steps, and wait for each step to complete before starting the next one. Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

You may create SSIS package and then create a Job and schedule it to your specific date and time

see http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb522537.aspx or 
http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms170057.aspx